# 'Setinterval' for slide show function is not working properly in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a simple image slide show here but images are not changing as I am expecting.

```
    const [bannerbg, setbannerbg] = useState({
    backgroundImage:
      "url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1864640/pexels-photo-1864640.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940')",
  });

  const [img2, setimg2] = useState({
    backgroundImage:
      "url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/1864653/pexels-photo-1864653.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1')",
  });

  const [img3, setimg3] = useState({
    backgroundImage: "url('https://cdn.wallpapersafari.com/15/98/I0tmB4.jpg')",
  });

  let i = 0;
  const sliderImages = [bannerbg, img2, img3];

  function backBannerChange() {
    if (i < sliderImages.length - 1) {
      i++;
    } else {
      i = 0;
    }

    setbannerbg(sliderImages[i]);
  }
  
  setInterval(backBannerChange,3000);
```

Html:-

```
<div className="disc-wrapper" style={bannerbg}></div>
```

First image is changing to second one but second image is not changing to third one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your function must set in lifecycle of component:

please use useeffect for this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
      setInterval(backBannerChange,3000);
 }, []);
```

Comment: But as far as I know Setinterval property triggers automatically after certain time when page loads. Then why we need to have useEffect here?

Comment: yes you are right it triggers but for change state you must hook your code in lifecycle of component